# Handle form submission on same page Spring Boot

Tags: javascript, java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am making a thymeleaf Spring Boot web application that takes in a filepath as input to a search bar and outputs the directories/files at that filepath. Currently the result are rendered on a separate thymeleaf page, but I am wondering how to change it so that the result is rendered on the same page, just below the search bar?

**Main Controller**

```
package net.javavatutorial.tutorials;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
class MainController
{
    
    @GetMapping("/")
    public String showForm(Model model) {
        Filename filename = new Filename();
        model.addAttribute("filename", filename);
        return "register_form";
    }
    
    @PostMapping("/register")
    public String submitForm(@ModelAttribute("filename") Filename filename) { 
        System.out.println(filename);
        return "register_success";
    }
    
}
```

**Thymeleaf Input/Landing Page with Search Bar**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>User Registration</title>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/styles.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<div align="center">
    <h1>File Finder</h1>
    <form action="#" th:action="@{/register}" method="post" th:object="${filename}">
        <input type="text" th:field="*{filename}" placeholder="Enter Filepath..."/>
        <button type="submit">Search</button>    
    </form>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Thymeleaf Output Page**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>File Finder</title>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/styles.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<div align="center">
    <h1>Files Found:</h1>
    <span th:text="${filename.filename}"></span><br/>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Filename.java**

```
public class Filename {

    private String filename; 
    
    public String getFilename() {
        return filename;
    }

    public void setFilename(String filename) {
        this.filename = Filewalk.filewalk(filename);
    }
    
}
```

**Filewalk.java program takes in file path and outputs files/directories contained at that file path**

```
import java.io.File; 

public class Filewalk {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(filewalk("H:\\jdk-15"));
    }
    
    public static String filewalk(String s) {
        String result = "";
        // creates a file object
        File file = new File(s);
        
        // returns an array of all files
        String[] fileList = file.list();
        
        for (String str : fileList) {
            result += str + ", "; //"\n";
        }
        
        return result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's what you can change to make it happen:

Controller:

```
@PostMapping("/register")
public String submitForm(@ModelAttribute("filename") Filename filename) { 
    ModelAndView view = new ModelAndView("register_form");
    view.addObject("filename", filename);
    return view;
}
```

Landing Page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>User Registration</title>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/styles.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<div align="center">
    <h1>File Finder</h1>
    <form action="#" th:action="@{/register}" method="post" th:object="${filename}">
        <input type="text" th:field="*{filename}" placeholder="Enter Filepath..."/>
        <button type="submit">Search</button>    
    </form>
</div>
</div>
<div class="container" th:if="${filename.filename != null}">
<div align="center">
    <h1>Files Found:</h1>
    <span th:text="${filename.filename}"></span><br/>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

This one should work for you :) Take care!

Comment: Thank you so much :) Because of the way I'm modifying the input (I just updated the question to show this) the search bar's input string gets replaced after clicking "search". How can I prevent this?